# data extraction from socket?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sockets, boost-asio

I am currently extracting data from the socket in the following way

```
            boost::asio::read_until( *socket, buffer, "\n", error ); 
            std::string s( (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(&buffer)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

it seems that the pulling mechanism is slow and I need to pull more data faster. Any suggestions on what I could do to improve performance ? IS there someway for me to create another socket and delegate some of the extraction work to that one?

Comment: first of all, try to move out `buffer` from cycle - it should not be re-created and re-allocated each time

Comment: *slow* is a relative term, what sort of performance are you expecting?

Comment: So you have profiled the code, and the profiler indicates the bottleneck is reading data from the socket?  Regardless, it may be worth minimizing the amount of memory allocations and deep copies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked on trading applications in the past and can tell you that I have never seen any order routing system or live quotes system ever implement a protocol where it searches for a "\n".  FIX certainly does not support this.  What this implies is that somewhere in your order routing or live quotes price system there is an app that is most likely taking those price quote messages which are probably using the FIX protocol and converting them to the protocol that you are now using.  This most likely has at least something to do with why the system is slow.

If each string represents a stock quote, then I would consider re-writing the system that is broadcasting price updates to send them in bulk and not send them more than say 3 - 5 times per second - assuming that the system is not used by automated trading programs (which would be an entirely different topic and require a much different approach).  It looks like that app is also sending the quotes in ascii text format.  I would change it to use a binary format.  FIX has supported a binary format for quite some time now and is called [FAST FIX](http://www.fixprotocol.org/fast).  A custom binary protocol would also be acceptable.

Depending on what kind of processing you are doing with the stock quote, I would consider not passing each quote to a different thread.  This is especially true if the only processing involves just updating a window with the new quote.  I would pass the entire buffer (assuming it has more than 1 quote and only contains quotes) for processing by the user interface thread.  If other processing needs to be done like saving it to disk or a database, then I would have a separate thread to handle that kind of processing.

You did not show us much code.  If the client app is slow, then you might try some of the following ideas for improvements:

1. Don't create threads on the fly.  Create a pool of threads at the beginning of the app and use them as required.  Understand that too many threads can be worse than just one thread, so try experimenting to find a happy balance when deciding on the number of threads.
2. In the same vein as above, try to create objects just once and reuse them when required.  This can be done by storing a set of objects in a vector, stack, or queue.  Only create a new object when 
   the container holding them has been exhausted.  This is especially true if your app frequently creates objects on the heap with the new operator.
3. In the code above, as Panasyuk pointed out, the buffer can be moved outside of the while loop.  The error object can as well.  Look for other areas in your code where you can create an object just once rather than create it over and over again.
4. Understand when an instance of an object is required .vs. a static one.  An instance of an object is typically required if multiple threads need to write to it.  A static object can be used when there is only one thread, or when there are multiple threads that only need to read from it.
5. When passing messages to the user interface thread from the thread that handles socket processing, make sure you use BeginInvoke as opposed to Invoke.  Invoke is synchronous and will wait for the called method to complete before it continues processing.  BeginInvoke is asynchronous and will return right away so it is more efficient.  If the app is dropping messages and Invoke is being used, then that could why.
6. Since the app is using multiple threads, it is reasonable to assume that there are some lock objects or statements used to prevent more than one thread from executing at the same time.  Look at those cases and make sure that the locks are granular in nature - meaning that the lock is not set at the top of a function for convenience .vs. setting it somewhere in the middle of a function where it is only needed.  Make sure that the code uses critical sections instead of mutexes as well since critical sections in Microsoft land are much more efficient.  The only time a mutex would need to be used is when attaching a DLL to two or more exes, which is rarely done anymore.